# Java TL1 protocol

Tags: java, open-source, sdk

Does anyone know of any Java SDKs/libraries for communicating via the TL1 protocol that are opensource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through this right now I can tell you there is nothing that is open and free.  There is the Perl TL1 toolkit https://noc.sara.nl/nrg/TL1-Toolkit/

What I ended up doing was writing my own TL1 Java api.  It's not particularly hard.  The most difficult part is handling all the different vendor implementations of the TL1 standard.  You could always reference the Perl toolkit as a starting point for rolling your own api.

The other option is using one of the commercial Java TL1 api's out there. Googling will find them pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bill.

I ended up writing my own API after all, too many different vendor implementations like you said.